# Elmah.ErrorMailModule.ReportError error throwing a FormatException, which recycles the w3wp process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

Recently, I've noticed that a web application in IIS is restarting randomly, sometimes every 20 minutes.  I've checked the Event Log, and found various errors of:

- Level: Error
- Source: .Net Runtime
- EventID: 1026

Below is the exception details:

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.FormatException
Stack:
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object[])
   at System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object[])
   at Elmah.ErrorMailModule.ReportError(Elmah.Error)
   at Elmah.ErrorMailModule.ReportError(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

I am using the latest stable version of Elmah (1.2.2).  Below is the `<elmah>` configuration node in web.config

```
<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/errors/" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorMail from="errors.visitgozo@casasoft-dev.com" to="errors@casasoft-dev" subject="{Error_Encountered} [Visit Gozo]" 
               async="true" smtpPort="25" smtpServer="mail.casasoft.com.mt" userName="errors@casasoft-automailer" password="RvjyBiyvePVVpcLBNgJ6" />

</elmah>
```

I am setting it to send such emails in async-mode (async="true").  If these are spawned on a background thread, and an error occurs on a backgroung thread, as far as I know the process is terminated.

Any ideas what can be done?

I am using IIS7, and ASP.Net MVC 4.

Comment: did you try to remove async flag, is it still failing?

Comment: @alexanderb yes, that is what I tried back then.  I've checked log files now, and it did not happen anymore.  But still, email sending is quite costly and I wouldn't want it happening on the main thread.

Comment: I agree, async is better.. but maybe it's not enought to just change that flag, maybe some elmah (or even iis) setting should be tweaked? unfortunately I never tried that case.

Answer (score 0):

I've raised an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=342) on Google Code related to ELMAH, and I got a reply from one of the developers.

Basically, it seems that the email subject is internally in Elmah using `string.Format()` to format it with the error message {0}, and error type {1}.  In my case, the subject I specified in the settings was:

```
{Error Encountered} Website_Name
```

The `{}` where triggering a FormatException, hence the issue.  This was easily resolved by replacing these with round-brackets, as I had no need for the curly brackets.  One could escape them by doing `{{` and `}}` , but in my case it was unnecessary.